# Python Dataframe data comparision

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two python DataFrames. Below is a scenario that i have.
Though this is just an example, but i would have millions of records with more then 100 columns. Basically, i need to compare the 2 dataFrames and create a third dataframe with the output that will have the column that has a difference, the column names and the values between two columns.

Here is the sample example.

DataFrame1:

```
EmpId         EmpName   LastName       Sal      Dept     BusinessUnit
10020         Victor    Oliver         12000    AI       Amazon
23100         Jen       Len            21220    Oracle   Google
41667         Roby      Alfredo        15000    Java     LinkedIn
55124         Chen      Frido          15662    Java     Facebook
```

DataFrame2:

```
EmpId         EmpName   LastName       Sal      Dept     BusinessUnit
10020         Victor    Oliver         12000    AI       Amazon
23100         Jen       Len            31220    Oracle   AAA+
41667         Roby      Chan           15000    Java     LinkedIn
55124         Chen      Frido          15662    Java     Facebook
```

Now DataFrame3 should have the result in the below format.

("Index/Primary key")

```
EmpId        Column_name     dataFrame1_data     dataFrame2_data
23100         Salary         21220                31220 
23100         BusinessUnit   Google               AAA+ 
41667         LastName       Alfredo              Chan
```

Comment: It's really difficult to understand the data you've shared in this format. Also, you haven't mentioned what tools you're using (e.g. pandas), so it's hard to give you an answer. It would be very helpful if you share some code to demonstrate how you're constructing the dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

First Import the DataFrames

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([[10020, 'Victor','Oliver',12000,'AI','Amazon'],
                 [23100 ,'Jen', 'Len' ,21220 ,'Oracle' ,'Google'],
                 [41667, 'Roby' ,'Alfredo' ,15000 ,'Java' ,'LinkedIn'] ,
                 [55124, 'Chen' ,'Frido' ,15662 ,'Java' ,'Facebook']])
df.columns=['EmpId','EmpName','LastName','Sal','Dept','BusinessUnit']
```

Data,

```
   EmpId EmpName LastName    Sal    Dept BusinessUnit
0  10020  Victor   Oliver  12000      AI       Amazon
1  23100     Jen      Len  21220  Oracle       Google
2  41667    Roby  Alfredo  15000    Java     LinkedIn
3  55124    Chen    Frido  15662    Java     Facebook
```

Import Second Dataframe

```
df2=pd.DataFrame([[10020, 'Victor','Oliver',12000,'AI','Amazon'],
                 [23100 ,'Jen', 'Len' ,31220 ,'Oracle' ,'AAAA+'],
                 [41667, 'Roby' ,'Chan' ,15000 ,'Java' ,'LinkedIn'] ,
                 [55124, 'Chen' ,'Frido' ,15662 ,'Java' ,'Facebook']])
df2.columns=['EmpId','EmpName','LastName','Sal','Dept','BusinessUnit']
```

Data,

```
   EmpId EmpName LastName    Sal    Dept BusinessUnit
0  10020  Victor   Oliver  12000      AI       Amazon
1  23100     Jen      Len  31220  Oracle        AAAA+
2  41667    Roby     Chan  15000    Java     LinkedIn
3  55124    Chen    Frido  15662    Java     Facebook
```

Melting the DataFrames

```
df1_melt=pd.melt(df,id_vars=['EmpId'])
df2_melt=pd.melt(df2,id_vars=['EmpId'])
```

Data,

```
    EmpId      variable     value
0   10020       EmpName    Victor
1   23100       EmpName       Jen
2   41667       EmpName      Roby
3   55124       EmpName      Chen
4   10020      LastName    Oliver
5   23100      LastName       Len
6   41667      LastName   Alfredo
7   55124      LastName     Frido
8   10020           Sal     12000
9   23100           Sal     21220
10  41667           Sal     15000
11  55124           Sal     15662
12  10020          Dept        AI
13  23100          Dept    Oracle
14  41667          Dept      Java
15  55124          Dept      Java
16  10020  BusinessUnit    Amazon
17  23100  BusinessUnit    Google
18  41667  BusinessUnit  LinkedIn
19  55124  BusinessUnit  Facebook
```

Merging the DataFrames Together,

```
pd.merge(df1_melt,df2_melt,how='inner',left_on=['EmpId','variable'],right_on=['EmpId','variable'])
```

Data,

```
    EmpId      variable   value_x   value_y
0   10020       EmpName    Victor    Victor
1   23100       EmpName       Jen       Jen
2   41667       EmpName      Roby      Roby
3   55124       EmpName      Chen      Chen
4   10020      LastName    Oliver    Oliver
5   23100      LastName       Len       Len
6   41667      LastName   Alfredo      Chan
7   55124      LastName     Frido     Frido
8   10020           Sal     12000     12000
9   23100           Sal     21220     31220
10  41667           Sal     15000     15000
11  55124           Sal     15662     15662
12  10020          Dept        AI        AI
13  23100          Dept    Oracle    Oracle
14  41667          Dept      Java      Java
15  55124          Dept      Java      Java
16  10020  BusinessUnit    Amazon    Amazon
17  23100  BusinessUnit    Google     AAAA+
18  41667  BusinessUnit  LinkedIn  LinkedIn
19  55124  BusinessUnit  Facebook  Facebook
```